# hortonworks website is NOT supporting download HDP Sandbox

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform

I am in need of HDP 2.3.2 on Sandbox for VMWARE,
but there seems a problem in Hortonworks website,and I can't find one for downloading on Internet.

Answer (score 3):

Go to http://hortonworks.com/downloads/ .There you will find "Hortonworks Sandbox Archive". You can expand this chapter and find all released sandboxes for VirualBox and VMWare

[image]

Comment: but it is always ‘loading’ and never begins to download.

Comment: Works for me (Firefox and Chrome). Deactivate your AdBocker and NoScript if you have. I encountred that I have this infinite loading like your when my adBlocker is activated.

Comment: I had the same problem where i clicked on submit and it just stayed on processing. i was on firefox. switched to chrome tried again. I got a pop up. Chose the right option and i was able to download. It is 11gb or more. Too bad they won't give it as a torrent since it showed me 12 hours to complete.